# Android activity finish() and onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity, back

Hello I am having trouble with something simple.

My App have the following Activity structure:

Home --- TO --- > Add

```
case R.id.menu_profiles_bAdd:
if (!(this instanceof Add)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Add.class));
    finish();
}
```

Then in the Add Activity I do some stuff and then

```
saveList();
startActivity(new Intent(Add.this, Home.class));
finish();
```

The Add Activity has android:parentActivityName="com.example.Home"

In this situation when I hit software or hardware BACK button, it directly closes my app.
I guess this is because Home Activity is "finished()".

On save button in the Add Activity hit, everything is ok.

---

What should I do to get the back button work correctly?

Thanks for the answers!

######## UPDATE

I did the suggested solution, but now there is a new problem.

Everything looks fine, but when I decide to exit from the app,
a Home activity (old one without the new added element) pops.

Comment: I think problem is that you start Add activity from To activity and simultaneously finish To activity.

Comment: It is better to use startActivityForResult in To activity and override onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

you do not required to finish Home Activity,you are finishing Home Activity at time of starting add activity.

update code

```
case R.id.menu_profiles_bAdd:
```

if (!(this instanceof Add)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Add.class));
    finish();
}

to

```
case R.id.menu_profiles_bAdd:
if (!(this instanceof Add)) {

startActivity(new Intent(this, Add.class));

}
```